# What is the difference between PEAR and PEAR2?

Tags: php, pear, pyrus

So there is the old pear installer and pyrus which is the new package manager for PEAR ... or was it PEAR2 ... at least it's faster and stuff.

And there is the old package.xml version <2.0 and the new package.xml >=2.0 ... is that version related to the package manager ... the pear installer or pyrus?

And what is PEAR2 actually? Why is there http://pear2.php.net/ and there is a version-agnostic 'PEAR' all over the site? Is it actually the same?

Could someone please explain to me how PEAR / PEAR2 / package.xml < and >= 2.0 / pear installer / Pyrus(.phar) are interrelated?

**EDIT 1**:

[Pyrus: Improvements from the PEAR Installer](http://pear.php.net/manual/en/pyrus.differences.frompear.php)

Basically states Pyrus is better than the old pear installer.

> Pyrus no longer supports package.xml
>   version 1.0

So what's going on with anything > 1.0?

> In addition, Pyrus has introduced
>   support for PEAR2 packages that can be
>   extracted to disk and then later
>   upgraded using Pyrus.

I'm sorry ... but is that propper English or is it just phrased confusingly? It seems to say that Pyrus also still supports PEAR ... and of course PEAR2. Still leaving the main question to be answered - what is PEAR2?

**EDIT 2**:

[PEAR2 & Pyrus - The look ahead](http://www.slideshare.net/helgith/pear2-pyrus-the-look-ahead)

It's a 2 years old outlook and slides for a presentation ... so mostly just keywords and -phrases.

So PEAR2 is a concept overhaul ... in which way?

Has a new installer ... Pyrus? ... but didn't the other source state that Pyrus has *introduced* support for PEAR2?

The constraints for package distribution seem to have changed ... only stable and PHPUnit coverage of at least 50% ...

The rest doesn't convey a clear meaning to me.

Comment: Pear.php.net should be very ashamed of themselves. Their "tutorial" is hardly usable unless you already know Pear (typical chicken-egg problem (or is it [pear-seed problem](https://hbr.org/2006/12/the-curse-of-knowledge)?)). For a real tutorial take a look at http://www.sitepoint.com/getting-started-with-pear/ instead.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

First of all, the PEAR repository and PEAR installer are two separate things.

PEAR2 is the next generation of the PEAR repository, Pyrus is the next generation of the PEAR installer.

The PEAR repository has a set of standards for all packages released there. Likewise, the PEAR2 repository has standards each package must conform to. Unfortunately wiki.php.net which has all the details is down at the moment, but here's the basic differences between PEAR standards and PEAR2 standards.

- PEAR2 packages are PHP 5.3+ only
- All code is under the PEAR2 namespace
- Each package must use package.xml v2.0
- Files autoload with PSR-0 autoloader
- require_once is not allowed
- Packages should not be tied to the filesystem they're installed to
- New versioning standards allow breaking BC without renaming the package
- Packages should extend SPL Exceptions, and implement a base Exception interface

Pyrus, the new installer, is actually a self-contained phar archive and requires no complex installation. The new installer supports many features that improve upon the original PEAR installer, and can install existing pear packages from pear.php.net, pear2.php.net, and other pear-compatible channels.

The code within the pyrus.phar file complies with the PEAR2 coding standards, and therefore is in the PEAR2 repository and can be installed if you'd like to use it as a vendor library.

With the pear installer you would use
`pear install pear/Net_URL2`

With pyrus, `php pyrus.phar install pear/Net_URL2`

When you install a package which conforms to the PEAR2 standards, you can safely move it to another location, commit to a repository, and the installs aren't tied to a specific machine. This makes it much easier to create a vendor directory containing libraries your application needs and share this with others.

There's quite a bit more, but that's the basics of PEAR2 and Pyrus.

Comment: Which source would you suggest for the "quite a bit more"? wiki.php.net? How about pear.php.net/manual/en? Is this manual not maintained anymore? Stuart Herbert is blogging about components-related stuff on his site (blog.stuartherbert.com). And he mentiones that he considers the manual on PEAR confusing and partly outdated. What is THE source on PEAR/PEAR2/Pyrus? Your web-site seems to be a very useful source as well.

Comment: The PHP wiki, wiki.php.net, has the up-to-date RFCs for the PEAR2 standards. The PEAR manual is very detailed, so it might not be as approachable as other basic tutorials. Some portions of the PEAR manual aren't up to date with what the PEAR group has voted on, specifically some of the PEAR2 sections. The wiki has the latest info, and I'll do what I can to get the PEAR2 sections of the PEAR manual updated.

Comment: @saltybeagle, Btw how did you know these stuff. Are you part of PHP core team?